# PHP URL ReWrites - .htaccess & MAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting, mamp

I have been playing around with this for ages, and just can't seem to get it to work - I don't know if it's an issue with .htaccess, or the fact that I'm using MAMP @ localhost:8888.

I'm trying to clean up my URLS from;

```
localhost:8888/profile.php?user=testuser
```

to

```
localhost:8888/testuser (localhost:8888 will be replaced by my TLD once live).
```

The code I'm trying to use in my `.htaccess` is;

```
RewriteEngine On
ReWriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ profile.php?user=$1
```

(I've also tried adding `http:/localhost:8888/` before the ^)

I am getting a `404`

Can anyone help, as this is driving me nuts!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are missing the /. Your ModRewrite does not recognize it by default. So your Browser is trying to find the folder "testuser" within your root directory.

Please have a look in here:

https://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?288690-Mod-Rewrite-simulating-a-folder-structure

**Edit:**

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /profile.php?user=$1
```

Comment: Do you mean a / as in;    
ReWriteRule ^([a-z]+)$ /profile.php?user=$1  ?   This is also still not working for me

Comment: No. You may try to use this RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ /profile.php?user=$1

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Youji - I'm still just getting a 404 ... I wonder if there is something to do with the fact that I'm using localhost..